# How to send angularjs expression content as a query string trough http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I have this code in my page:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="bus in buses | filter:query" name="Bus">
        <h3>{{bus.name}}</h3>
        <p>A {{bus.distance}} Km</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And I would like to send a HTTP request to a webpage (like map.html?Bus=AAA) when I click on a `<li>` element as I would do with a form:

```
<form action="list.html" method="get">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
          Select one:
        </div>
        <select name="Select">
          <option >Option A</option>
          <option selected>Option B</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Line" name="Line">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Stop" name="Stop">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Key Word" name="Key">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-full button-energized"  type="submit" value="Submit">
    Search
  </button>
      </form>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `ng-click` in your li tag, and create a submit function on your controller:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="bus in buses | filter:query" name="Bus" ng-click="submit(bus.name)">
        <h3>{{bus.name}}</h3>
        <p>A {{bus.distance}} Km</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and Controller:

```
$sope.submit = function(name){
  var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            };

  var data = {
         BUS : name
        };

  $http.post("/map.html", data, config )
           .success(function (data) {
                //do something if success
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                //do something if error

            });
};
```

you can use the method get too. take a look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: There are some errors, like $sope.submit and $http.post(/map.html, data, config ) instead of $http.post('/map.html', data, config ) but it doesn't work because i get 404. If I use get the request goes smoothly but the page doesn't load.

Comment: well, i dont know the conditions u are using the url, but try to take of the "/" and let just "map.html", well for the reload u must use $location... so u can redirect the page too... or u can just change the $http.post ou .get, to a simple javascript submit request..